# Logic Flow Flaw in custom html builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I set out to create a simple html builder for myself basically it works like this:

My syntax is as follows:

id1,id2 <- comma separated would produce 2 div groups

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id1Inner"></div>
</div>

<div id="id2">
    <div id="id2Inner"></div>
</div>
```

You can also do inner classes with clearfix added to its inner parent as such: (* denotes class, ! denotes id)

id1*class1*class2,id2!id1!id2

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id1Inner" class="clearfix">
        <div class="class1"></div>
        <div class="class2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="id2">
    <div id="id2Inner" class="clearfix">
        <div id="id1"></div>
        <div id="id2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem happens when I try to mix adding inner classes (*) and ids (!) such as this:

id1*class1!id1

This ***SHOULD*** create the following block - however I am at a loss now for how to get there.

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id1Inner" class="clearfix">
        <div class="class1"></div>
        <div id="id1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live preview my script:
http://labs.remixdesigninc.com/builder/index.html

Code Reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        window.buildIT = function(htmlItems){
            count = htmlItems.length;

            // First character remove special characters (Allow Letters, Number)
            for (i=0; i<count; i++){
                htmlItems[i] = htmlItems[i].replace(/^[^a-z]/i, "");
            }

            // build HTML
            for (x=0; x<count; x++){

                var currentItemClass = htmlItems[x].indexOf("*");
                var currentItemID = htmlItems[x].indexOf("!");

                // Check for Sub Class or Sub ID
                if ((currentItemClass >= 0) || (currentItemID >= 0)){

                    // Check for Sub Class
                    if (currentItemClass >= 0){

                        // For Classes
                        var splitSubClass = htmlItems[x].split('*');

                        makeString = '<div id="' + splitSubClass[0].toLowerCase() + '">\n\t<div id="' + splitSubClass[0].toLowerCase() + 'Inner" class="clearfix">\n';
                        for (y=1; y<splitSubClass.length; y++){
                            makeString += '\t\t<div class="' + splitSubClass[y].toLowerCase() + '"></div>\n';
                        }
                        makeString += '\t</div>\n\</div>\n\n';

                        $("code").append(document.createTextNode(makeString));              

                    }

                    // Check for Sub ID
                    if (currentItemID >= 0){

                        // For IDs
                        var splitSubID = htmlItems[x].split('!');

                        makeString = '<div id="' + splitSubID[0].toLowerCase() + '">\n\t<div id="' + splitSubID[0].toLowerCase() + 'Inner" class="clearfix">\n';
                        for (z=1; z<splitSubID.length; z++){
                            makeString += '\t\t<div id="' + splitSubID[z].toLowerCase() + '"></div>\n';
                        }
                        makeString += '\t</div>\n\</div>\n\n';

                        $("code").append(document.createTextNode(makeString));

                    }

                } else {
                    alert(htmlItems[x] + " does not have an * in it");
                    // No Sub Child
                    makeString = '<div id="' + htmlItems[x].toLowerCase() + '">\n\t<div id="' + htmlItems[x].toLowerCase() + 'Inner">\n\t</div>\n </div>\n\n';
                    $("code").append(document.createTextNode(makeString));
                }
            }

        }

        $("#btnCreate").click(function(){
            $("code").html("");
            var htmlItems = $("#text").val();

            if (htmlItems){
                htmlItems = htmlItems.replace(/ /g, "");                //remove all spaces
                htmlItems = htmlItems.replace(/[^a-z0-9,\-_*!]/gi, ""); //remove special characters (Allow Letters, Numbers, and _ -)
                htmlItems = htmlItems.split(',');                       //create array out of items using comma as separator
                if(htmlItems != ""){
                    buildIT(htmlItems);
                } else {
                    alert("Nothing to create.");
                }
                $("#text").val(htmlItems);                  
            } else {
                alert("Nothing to create.");
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but `(* denotes class, ! denotes id)`??? Wouldn't you be better off with standards like `(. denotes class, # denotes id)` so that it is *more* readable to jQuery and CSS folks :)

Comment: Haha very fair comment - I am open to this!

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle of your page to make it easier for others to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/m9ng6jv5/

Comment: Note: Does that `*` in your regex needs to be escaped `\*`?

Comment: The * has worked as is - so I assume it probably doesn't. I am not a regex expert however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having comes from the fact that once you identify that their is a subitem with a class or id, you never take into account that there could be mixed classes and ids in the same div.  You are probably better off finding the outer id then consuming the subitem string a piece at a time to make each child item.  Try this:

```
window.buildIT = function(htmlItems){
    count = htmlItems.length;

    // First character remove special characters (Allow Letters, Number)
    for (i=0; i<count; i++){
        htmlItems[i] = htmlItems[i].replace(/^[^a-z]/i, "");
    }

    // build HTML
    for (x=0; x<count; x++){
        var item = htmlItems[x];
        var firstSubClassPos = item.indexOf("*");
        var firstSubIdPos = item.indexOf("!");

        if (firstSubClassPos < 0) {
            firstSubClassPos = item.length;
        }
        if (firstSubIdPos < 0) {
            firstSubIdPos = item.length;
        }

        var subItemStart = firstSubClassPos < firstSubIdPos ? firstSubClassPos : firstSubIdPos;

        var outerId = item.substring(0, subItemStart);
        //make the outer divs
        var makeString = '<div id="' + outerId.toLowerCase() + '">\n\t';

        var subItems = item.substring(subItemStart, item.length);
        if (subItems.length > 0) {
            makeString += '<div id="' + outerId.toLowerCase() + 'Inner" class="clearfix">\n';
        } else {
            makeString += '<div id="' + outerId.toLowerCase() + 'Inner">\n';
        }

        while(subItems.length > 0) {
            var isClass = subItems[0] == '*';
            subItems = subItems.substring(1, subItems.length);
            var nextClassPos = subItems.indexOf('*');
            var nextIdPos = subItems.indexOf('!');
            if (nextClassPos < 0) {
                nextClassPos = subItems.length;
            }
            if (nextIdPos < 0) {
                nextIdPos = subItems.length;
            }
            var nextDelimiterPos = nextClassPos < nextIdPos ? nextClassPos : nextIdPos;
            var marker = subItems.substring(0, nextDelimiterPos);
            var markerType = isClass ? 'class' : 'id';
            makeString += '\t\t<div ' + markerType + '="' + marker + '"></div>\n';
            subItems = subItems.substring(nextDelimiterPos, subItems.length);
        }
        //close our outer divs
        makeString += '\t</div>\n</div>\n\n';
        $("code").append(document.createTextNode(makeString));
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a70z2mk6/1/)

Comment: This works very well! Only thing I see it's missing is the clearfix class being added if their are sub classes! Thank you for this!

Comment: @remixdesign I missed that.  I've updated the answer and fiddle to take care of that.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.